# Apply JS to dynamically created divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div's on my page, that can be added to the page dynamically, and can also be removed.

On page load, the dynamically created div's are loaded from `localStorage` with uniqiue id's and a **common class depending on the div**, and I call a function along with that, `content()`.

The function `content()` looks like this:

```
function content(){
    alert("test");
    $(".two button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
}
```

Pretty simple, all it does is alert "test" when the function is called, and if you click `.two` `<button>`, it will alert `.two` `<textarea>` `.val()`.

This works fine once the div's have been loaded, but I run into the problem when I clone the div's

When I clone the div's, it gives them a unique id and a common class like above. At the end of `cloneDiv()`, I call `content()`, so that clicking on the elements inside will produce the same results as above.

The problem is, the function will get called as many times as there are div's on the screen, but also means that clicking on the `<button>` in div `.two` will alert `.two` `<textarea>` `.val()` **three times**.

TLDR; Clicking on the button in `.two` get's called as many times as there are div's on the screen, as the function is called once the dynamic div is created, but should only be called once.

There's a lot of code to do all this, but I think I explained what happens pretty clearly. I will however whip up a demo if that would help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what "event delegation" is for.  You set up a handler on the document and it will handle events from its descendants, even if they are created after the handler is attached:

```
$(document).on("click", ".two button", function(){
// put a click hander on the document to process clicks
// from buttons that are descendants of elements with class=two
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.two button', function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

I would change the `'body'` part of that to the real container of these buttons.  So say the buttons are always inside a content div with id `my-div`, you'd do:

```
$('#my-div').on('click', '.two button', function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

You also only need this code to run once, so no need to put it in a function that gets called multiple times.  Just put it in your `$(document).ready(....)`.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/dxbqz/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: "At the end of cloneDiv(), I call content(), so that clicking on the elements inside will produce the same results as above." What happens is that you are compounding the events on to the existing elements so that is why you get so many callbacks. You should instead use the `.on` function, and use it only once. If you call `.on` multiple times it will produce the same results because multiple events will be registered.

```
$(".two button").on("click",function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Do this **once**, every button matching `(".two button")` will respond to it, even if appended later.

Another approach would be to pass in the element to the content() call and then mark it up from there if you are always calling this function when creating the elements anyway.

```
function content(element){
 $(element).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
 });
}
```

As a side note, using alerts to debug can be problematic as they interrupt program execution. I would highly recommend using `console.log(id)` instead and then looking in the console for your testing variables. `console.trace()` is also a good one to keep in mind if you are using a third party script and need to see what went wrong where.